Hadoop/Iceberg version conflict when reading/writing files via Spark
I'm trying to read a parquet file from an S3 object store (a MinIO server) into a Spark dataframe, then append to an Iceberg table.
I have the following software versions:

Spark 3.5 w/ scala 2.12
Iceberg Spark runtime 1.5.0
Nessie integration 0.79 (most likely not causing any problem)
Hadoop 3.3.4
awssdk:bundle & awssdk:url-connection-client both 2.20.131

This however causes a ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.closeQuietly(java.lang.AutoCloseable, software.amazon.awssdk.thirdparty.org.slf4j.Logger)' exception. Looking into GitHub,
it looks like a problem with the AWS SDK versioning; also this mailing list conversation points out how he's trying to do the same as me but not finding a combination of versions that works.
I have been looking at a version matrix that helps solve this, to no avail. Any of these questions would be of help if answered:

Can anyone point out to a version matrix for hadoop/spark/awssdk?
Or, is there a way to solve these dependencies automatically via some package manager?

